# R Session Startup Failure

Tags: rstudio

I tried to install the newest version of R Studio (RStudio 2022.07.0+548, "Spotted Wakerobin") on my 5 year old machine.  Now I get the error below.  I have uninstalled R and tried it again with the same result.

Any advice? Thanks for the help.

[image: RStudio Error message]

Comment: What version of R do you have installed?

Comment: I installed R 4.2.1 after this problem showed up initially. Thanks.

Comment: Has the problem been solved then?

Comment: No, I have uninstalled everything and reinstalled R first then RStudio.  Same error.

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Global Options, what does it show under "R Version"? If you click on "Change..." and navigate to where R is installed (typically "C:\Progam Files\R\...") and restart RStudio, does that solve it?

Comment: Thank you Phil for looking into my issue.  I just resolved it.  The uninstall of the previous version of R did not remove all the files.  I think RStudio was still calling on the previous version. Seems like I could have figured this out myself, apologies. Thanks to community here for being a resource for us troglodytes.

Comment: heh no worries, glad it worked out